# Having issue achieving a certain effect in a nav-bar with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Good evening,

Recently one of my clients hired an illustrator to redesign his website. He came up with an interesting design, and I was handed the task of changing our old style.

I have had no issue with the rest of the site, but the navbar as he designed it has given me headaches. It is like this:

[image: Navbar issue]
As seen in the red circle, the image logo overlaps the navbar and seemlessly transitions to the main page.

Among my main problems is that I have absolutely no idea how that effect is called, and I find it impossible to search for it. I tried a few hacks (making the brand image a picture on top of the nav-bar with different shadows, making an overlay button on top of the nav-bar, etc.) but with no success. Does anyone have any idea how this effect can be achieved? I'd hate to ask the client if he would consider dropping this, but I am more of a programmer and much less of a designer.

I have no problem using an external library or a framework to achieve this, I just desperately need a pointer as to what on earth that style is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG or transparent png are better options, otherwise using CSS you can achieve this effect. Use the below code for taking an idea:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.curve {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.curve:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 0 50% 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 999px #333;
}

.rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #333;
}


/*Example 2*/

div.s {
  background: #333;
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
}

div.s:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, rgba(204, 0, 0, 0) 100px, #333 100px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
}

div.s:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0 / 0 0 100% 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="curve"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>

</div>


<!--Example 2-->
<div class="s">

</div>
```

See the codepen: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/BZEpLO

Comment: Thank you so much! Will be checking it now.

Comment: You welcome. If you feel appropriate vote up my answer and accept as well :) If you still need any help any time comment here.

Comment: Accepting the question will close the topic